# With JavaScript append Razor

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

```
    $("#tabs").append(
            "<div id='tabs-" + tabCounter + "'>" +
                "<div class='divTable'>" +
                    "<div class='divRow'>" +
                        "<div class='divCell'>" +
                            "<div class='editor-label'>" +
                                "@Html.LabelFor(m => m.name)" +
                            "</div>" +
                        "</div>" +
                        "<div class='divCell'>" +
                            "<div class='editor-field'>" +
                                "@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.employee[0].name)" +
                            "</div>" +
                        "</div>" +
                    "</div>" +
```

Why does not work? Razor-Code is not recognized?

Comment: What kind of error do you get?

Comment: Where is this script located in your cshtml file?  What is the HtmlHelper being converted into if you see it at all in the generated HTML/JS?

Comment: no, an external javascript file

Comment: I want to insert employees dynamic in a database .. with jquery tabs

Answer (score 0):

Double quotes before razor code is not valid. Razor code is just like your c sharp code remove the double quotes.